# Javafx: avoid thread-code in Model Setters

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface, javafx-2

Im trying javafx for the first time. In my Model i hava a property that tells if my app is connected or not. There is a connectionListener somewhere else that calls `connection.setConnectionState(state)` when the value changes.

Problem is i got Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
```

This makes sense, as i attempted to change the UI in a thread that wasnt an UI-thread. So i added `Platform.runLater(..)` to my setter and it works.

Question: My setters will get very ugly if i have to do this for every property. Is there some nice/correct way to this in javafx?

Model:

```
public class Connection {

    private final StringProperty connectionStateProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty getConnectionStateProperty() {
        return connectionStateProperty;
    }   

    public void setConnectionState(final ConnectionState connectionState) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                connectionStateProperty.setValue(connectionState.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
public class ConnectionController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Label connectionLabel;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        Bindings.bindBidirectional(connectionLabel.textProperty(),
            connection.getConnectionStateProperty());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [fx-guice](https://github.com/cathive/fx-guice) project there is a method annotation called @FxApplicationThread which will run the method on the FX thread as long the object was injected via guice, I've found this really easy to use and clean.

Comment: sounds promising. i have weld as my di container atm, but gonna how i can use something similiar, btw do you think my code makes sense or should this be done differently?

Comment: Yes your code is very clear.  There is one other way I thought of in the past but never implemented.  If there was an implementation of the ObjectProperty class that was thread safe but fired all events on the FX thread the code would be transparent.